# Size of Mongo shard for efficient backups

Tags: mongodb

What is the recommended size of a shard for efficient backups? One of the operations team guy mentioned that they have 3 shards with 350GB data and takes 12.5 hours to backup! If max data loss permitted is 5 minutes, is it possible to do every 5 minutes transaction backups in MongoDB? What tool is available to do transaction backups?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a website for software developers. But your question needs the expertise of a database administrator. Therefor I nominated this question for migration to https://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "transaction backups" since MongoDB doesn't support transactions in the first place. [MMS Backup](http://mms.mongodb.com/help/backup/) offers an incremental backup service. There's no built-in tool for incremental backups in MongoDB (2.6).